# How to read date out of a datepicker Angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have a application in Angular 8 and a search form. So A user can select a date with a datepicker. And then a api call will search for that date.

But for now I will get this error:

```
ExtendedSearchComponent.html:41 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

the thml looks like this:

```
  <div class="search-fields-inputs">
      <mat-form-field class="search-field-input">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate" placeholder="sinds" [(ngModel)]="startDate.date" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #startDate  [(ngModel)]="startDate.date" ngDefaultControl (selectedChanged)="onDate($event)"></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

buttons:

```
 <div fxFlex="none">
        <div fxLayout="row">
          <div class="is-grouped">
            <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="Button" (click)="searchFor()">Zoek</button>&nbsp;
            <button mat-raised-button color="secondary" class="Button">Clear</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

and the ts code looks like this:

```
startDate: Date;
 // endDate: Date;

  constructor( private participantService: ParticipantService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.searchExtended) {
      this.searchExpanded = changes.searchExtended.currentValue;
    }
  }

/*   public onDate(event): void {
    this.startDate.date = event;
    this.getData(this.roomsFilter.date);
  } */

  searchFor( filterRegistration : FilterByRegistrationDTO) {

   console.log(this.participantService.filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, "Invited", this.startDate.toString()).subscribe(result => {
  //  this.startDate = filterRegistration.start.value;
   console.log(result);
   console.log(this.startDate);


   }));


  }
```

Thank you

if I do this:

```
  <div class="search-fields-inputs">
      <mat-form-field class="search-field-input">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDate" placeholder="sinds" [(ngModel)]="startDate" />
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #startDate  [(ngModel)]="startDate" ngDefaultControl (selectedChanged)="onDateChanged()"></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

I get this error:

```
core.js:12584 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
    at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (compiler.js:6440)
```

Comment: The error means your variable is undefined. Try giving it a value ?

Comment: I already tired this: 1, "Invited", this.startDate.value

Comment: ?? What is then the ans ware??

Comment: you've used the same variable name "startDate" inside ts file as well as for <mat-datepicker #startDate>, change it to a different variable and assign the same variable to [for] property of <mat-datepicker-toggle>. I have already created the fork and you've marked it as answer. Have a look at it, I've used different variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't assigned the `startDate` to any value, you must be getting another error saying that cannot read 'date' of undefined. Also it's not needed, you can directly bind `'startDate'` variable to `ngModel`.

Replace `[(ngModel)]="startDate.date"` with `[(ngModel)]="startDate"`

I've created a fork here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5r6u3p

> component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [(ngModel)]="startDate">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

 <button mat-raised-button color="accent" class="Button" (click)="searchFor()">Search</button>
```

> component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Datepicker selected value */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  startDate: Date;

  searchFor() {
   console.log(this.startDate.toString());
   };
}
```